# List all channel in Hyperledger Fabric network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

How can I list all the channels within a fabric network? Is it possible to do it with using `peer` cli?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to know the "List of channels peer has joined", with peer cli, but not possible for the whole network.
The command is:

```
peer channel list [flags]
```

Link:

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/commands/peerchannel.html#

Comment: I was looking for something for the whole network, but thank you!